# What's considered a threat?

Tags: malware, antivirus

I have troubles to understand what is exactly a threat.
If I've an antivirus able to catch some malware, is this malware still considered a threat to my computer.

Comment: Yes, a virus is still a threat, no matter if it is blocked by your antivirus. If it wasn't a threat, you wouldn't need the antivirus, would you? You might be confused by the fact that with an antivirus the risk of infection is reduced, so you feel safer. But technically a threat remains the same, what changes after you install an antivirus is the actually the "risk".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The malware is a threat to your computer because it intends to create harm or could create a hazard that could result in harm to your computer.

Your anti-virus is a mitigation to that threat. You hope that the mitigation works and works the way you expect it to in order to avoid the harm.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, a threat remains a threat even when there are protective assets and measures against it?
The malicious intent is enough to qualify something as a threat?

Comment: The potential for harm is enough. Something can be a threat without any intent, which I was sure to include in my answer. Storms are a threat, but they have no intent.